# Is there a pre-built Bolts.framework for Objective-C available?

Tags: parse-platform, back4app, bolts-framework

We have tried to update our `Bolts.framework` (to remove `UIWebView` references) from the GitHub sources and failed. And the one provided on back4app.com is out of date.

Does anyone know if there is an already built `Bolts.framework` ZIP file posted anywhere with the latest updates?

Comment: Hi Allan, you can download it directly on its repository, here it is: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC

Comment: Hi @Charles. Thank you for responding! Alas, I downloaded that a week ago but I don't see an actual built framework there and still can't get it to build in xCode. I'm an old fart (51) and despite having had apps in the App Store for 10 years, I can't this this one to build! I was hoping someone could build it and zip up the built framework?

Answer (score 4):

I spend almost whole day to built this lib, so few steps to build Bolts:

1. Download latest release https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC/releases
2. After that download xtoolchain from https://github.com/parse-community/xctoolchain-archive
3. Move files and folders from xtoolschain folder to **Bolts/Vendor/xtoolchain**
4. So now you can build Bolts running command **sh build_all.sh** from **Bolts/scripts**
5. In Bolts folder you can found build folder and the framework will be here **build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts.framework**

Comment: Hi Andrey Thanks for responding. I did as you said but when I type "sh build_all.sh" in that directory the script outputs errors about the script trying to remove the Bolts directory itself and exits. Argh! Any chance you can post the resulting framework somewhere as a ZIP?

Comment: Sure, here is the zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezb4n65bvrvwmc9/Bolts.framework.zip?dl=0